# Are there further estimation techniques for this convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was solving the following problem:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence where $a_1 = 2$, and $a_{n+1}$ is defined by $(n+1)a_{n+1}^2= na_n^2+a_n$. I aim to show that $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_i^2}{i^2}<2$.

Initially, I found a relatively straightforward solution by observing that $a_n > a_{n+1} > 1$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{(n-\frac12)(n+\frac12)} = \frac{1}{n^2-\frac14}$ hold.

However, I attempted to find a better estimation for the series but could only derive the inequality:

$$
\frac{a_n^2}{n^2} < \frac{a_n^2}{n} - \frac{a_n^2}{n+1}
$$

which holds for all $n>2$, and since $\frac{a_n^2}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, I obtained:

$$
\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_i^2}{i^2}=\frac{3}{4} + \sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{n^2}< \frac{3}{4} + \frac{6+\sqrt{3}}{9}.
$$

I'm seeking further estimation techniques or a precise evaluation of the series. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. My code shows that it approaches around $1.5791$ ($n=1000000$)

Comment: If you want to find a better bound, you start the telescoping series later. EG $\sum a_i^2 / i^2 < 3/4 + a_3^2/(3-1/2) = 1.781$. The savings are obtained by having more accurate calculations of $a_i^2 / i^2$, so it does take a while to under 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

As your sequence is decreasing, you could try the following to get an arbitrarily good estimate:
$$\sum\limits_{i = 2}^{\infty} \frac{a_i^2}{i^2} = \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n \frac{a_i^2}{i^2} + \sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i^2}{i^2} < \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n \frac{a_i^2}{i^2} + a_{n+1}^2\sum\limits_{i = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} = \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n \frac{a_i^2}{i^2} + a_{n+1}^2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}\right).$$
Of course, you could do this by hand to get a precise algebraical expression for each $n$, but it probably makes more sense to compute it numerically. As you already ran some code anyway, this should be easy to implement.

Comment: Much appreciated! However, is it possible to perform other algebraic transformations by hand to get a better estimation, rather than simply using $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: @Flaming I don't know, sorry.